# parsing site with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i'm trying to learn how to parse html with python
and i`m currently stuck with soup.findAll return me an empty array,therefore there are elements which could be found
Here is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/tennis/20191114/'

responce = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, 'html.parser')

info = soup.findAll('tr', {'class':'odd deactivate'})

print(info)
```

i`ll appreciate any help,thanks in advance

Comment: They could be added dynamically. Have you checked what IS in `responce`?

Comment: I don't see any both 'odd deactivate' tr in the page, there is no 'deactivate' at all

Comment: You should include a minimal sample of `response.text` to complete your [mcve].

Comment: there are plenty of it, https://imgur.com/qsZ9lw2
@BlueSheepToken, i just checked and it seems there is no such tags in responce,does it mean they are added dynamically and i can`t reach it?

Comment: It seems that "odd deactivate" doesn't exist in `responce`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the page only loades the "odds" parts once it is called in a browser. So you could use [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) and [Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Note that you need to download the Chrome driver and place the driver in your `.../python/` directory. Make sure you choose a matching driver version, meaning a version of Chrome driver that matches the version of the Chrome browser you have installed.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from urllib.request import urlopen 
import requests, time, traceback, random, csv, codecs, re, os

# Webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/tennis/20191114/'
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
info = soup.findAll('tr', {'class':'odd deactivate'})
print(info)
```

Comment: Read the error: Get you a Chrome driver version that is matching your Chrome browser version you have installed on your computer. Check Chrome version like -> help -> about Google Chrome in your browser

Answer (score 2):

> i'm trying to learn how to parse html with python

You happened to pick a webpage which isn't very beginner-friendly when it comes to webscraping. Broadly speaking, most webpages use one or both of these two common methods for loading / displaying data:

- The user makes a request to a server (visits a page, for example).
  The server gets the necessary data from a database. The server
  generates an HTML response using a templating engine, and returns the
  response for the user's browser to render.
- The user makes a request to a server. The server returns an
  HTML-skeleton response which gets populated with data dynamically by
  making other requests / using APIs etc.

The webpage you picked is of the second type. Just because you can see the `<tr>` elements in the "Elements" tab of Chrome's Dev Tools doesn't mean that that's what the server sent you. By looking at the network tab of Chrome's Dev Tools you can see that a request is made to these two resources:
[https://fb.oddsportal.com/ajax-next-games/2/0/1/20191114/yje3d.dat?*=1574007087150*](https://fb.oddsportal.com/ajax-next-games/2/0/1/20191114/yje3d.dat?_=1574007087150)
[https://fb.oddsportal.com/ajax-next-games-odds/2/0/X0/20191114/1/yje3d.dat?=1574007087151](https://fb.oddsportal.com/ajax-next-games-odds/2/0/X0/20191114/1/yje3d.dat?_=1574007087151)

(The Query String parameters will not be the same for you. Visiting those urls also won't be very interesting unless you provide the right payload.)

The first resource seems to be a jQuery script which makes a request, the response of which contains HTML (this is your table). It looks something like this:

[image]

You can see that they seem to have assigned unique IDs to each of the matches. Giron Marcos vs. Holt Brandon in this case has an ID of `ATM9GmXG`.

The second resource is similar. It's also a jQuery script which seems to be making a request to their main API. The response this time is JSON, which is always desirable for webscraping. Here's what part of that looks like (notice the same ID):

[image]