# Trying to scrape an HTML span value by class, but returns error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
def getDOW():
    DowURL = ["https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EDJI?p=^DJI"]
    # requests data on the website(s) above
    page = requests.get(DowURL, headers=headers)

    # parses HTML text from website
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    # title = soup.find(class_="D(ib) Fz(18px)").get_text()
    name = soup.find(class_= "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()
    print (name)
```

Returns the error:

```
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s' % url")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EDJI?p=^DJI']'
```

I'm sorry if this was already asked before, but I'm new to BeautifulSoup so I wasn't sure what was going on. If anybody could help me, or advise me, that would be much appreciated. I am trying to scrape values from several sites, failed to do so using a list, so made separate functions (I know how redundant this is) and ran into this error.

Comment: Why you use a list for URL? You need to provide a URL (string) or index your list `DowURL[0]`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the brackets were the problem. Thanks @HTF

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the HTML source of the page, you will find, that the object you are interested in, is not present. The reason likely is, that the content is loaded only once you load the page in a browser. You can use [Selenium and Chrome driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58902915/9524424) to do this. However, it is not very efficient to load the data like this. I did this in the past and it was not a good solution.

Since you seem to be interested in stock prices, you could use this approach:

```
import yfinance as yf
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2019,11,15)
end = datetime.datetime(2019,11,16)
data = yf.download('^DJI', start=start, end=end)
print(data)
```

Result:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 downloaded
                Open      High       Low     Close  Adj Close     Volume
Date
2019-11-14  27757.20  27800.71  27676.97  27781.96   27781.96  303970000
2019-11-15  27843.54  28004.89  27843.54  28004.89   28004.89  283720000
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will check this out

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import datetime
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn import cluster, covariance, manifold


start = '2019-02-01'
end = '2020-02-01'

tickers = ['DJIA']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])

#names = np.reshape(price_data, (len(price_data), 1))

names = pd.concat(price_data)
names.reset_index()
```

Result:

```
          Date ticker          Open     Adj Close
0   2019-02-01   DJIA  25025.310547  25063.890625
1   2019-02-04   DJIA  25062.119141  25239.369141
2   2019-02-05   DJIA  25287.929688  25411.519531
3   2019-02-06   DJIA  25371.570312  25390.300781
4   2019-02-07   DJIA  25265.810547  25169.529297
..         ...    ...           ...           ...
247 2020-01-27   DJIA  28542.490234  28535.800781
248 2020-01-28   DJIA  28594.279297  28722.849609
249 2020-01-29   DJIA  28820.529297  28734.449219
250 2020-01-30   DJIA  28640.160156  28859.439453
251 2020-01-31   DJIA  28813.039062  28256.029297

[252 rows x 4 columns]
```

Note: you can pass in any tickers you want, so change this line:

```
tickers = ['DJIA']
```

To this:

```
tickers = ['MMM',
'ABT',
'ABBV',
'ABMD',
'ACN',
'ATVI']
```

And you will get data for multiple tickers, like this.

Result:

```
           Date ticker        Open   Adj Close
0    2019-02-01    MMM  201.490005  190.939163
1    2019-02-04    MMM  199.009995  191.945831
2    2019-02-05    MMM  200.720001  192.818268
3    2019-02-06    MMM  201.220001  194.208420
4    2019-02-07    MMM  201.020004  191.591080
        ...    ...         ...         ...
1507 2020-01-27   ATVI   58.189999   58.320000
1508 2020-01-28   ATVI   58.790001   60.029999
1509 2020-01-29   ATVI   60.490002   60.400002
1510 2020-01-30   ATVI   59.919998   60.889999
1511 2020-01-31   ATVI   60.200001   58.480000

[1512 rows x 4 columns]
```