# How can I crawl the product items from shopee website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I try to use python to get the product information like Name and Price.
But this time doesn't work, even I check the html code via web-browser programmer mode to get the class name and try to use this name to get anything what i want.

But I got the result like that, I cannot find any the items of `"class_="col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item"`, should I add more header information?

the print result

- print(r.status_code)-->200
- print(r.history)-->[]
- print(r.url)-->https://shopee.tw/shop/1819984/search?shopCollection=9271157
- print(len(items))-->0

````
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import json

url = 'https://shopee.tw/shop/1819984/search?shopCollection=9271157'
headers = {
'Host': 'shopee.tw',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0',
'Cookie':'SPC_IA=-1; SPC_EC=-; SPC_F=L07IMDECRHjifEKyg7XuNCJ00GNdJGTA; REC_T_ID=246cfcdc-18fa-11ea-b254-f8f21e2be0b8; SPC_T_ID="Fyr1skVDq7FDiJOuTYHBmMfMr2Cw1eZyPbYJhBYoRmf/gvfvkOf5zgjIVXLrYYlg32aSx1PfmhWq7QsQzwM86mdeXG8VU7ERK4N+gfPFd14="; SPC_U=-; SPC_T_IV="/oJN8EB7iQwg7+n5mXd6cw=="; _gcl_au=1.1.788704691.1575727322; _fbp=fb.1.1575727322914.443117835; _ga=GA1.2.1422761069.1575727324; __BWfp=c1575727332595xf5a099d8b; cto_lwid=7ea874b3-f31f-47d7-aef9-60eed0156d33; cto_bundle=0tgQ7V9rU3JlRTU4aWlTc09JNXRaN014Y3ZXa1BtVVcwT2RhOU1UZ0tweUFvWUo2WHRPQjd0JTJCM1duaG5iWXFFRWxpbHZkTFluWUZLSEFudTFreGJueFoxU0EyanhnMWN6ZEVIUVV6cFlhd050emhFMWQ4bmhVelZwVSUyRmwwQUp5c29lOEhPT2ZobE10S1dvT09HYWNhVXV1YWx5R3dSOGw0MHcwZWpiZ2pXU2VHSzdrJTNE; _med=refer; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; fbm_382498665271383=base_domain=.shopee.tw; SPC_SI=jq6hwq6ju6hig9hfulumcagdqaiopatc; _gid=GA1.2.143857303.1577796150; csrftoken=3Pya3o5WYEvhLOj9FqCqbV3angfwBlko; AMP_TOKEN=%24NOT_FOUND; _dc_gtm_UA-61915057-6=1'
}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers,allow_redirects=True)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.history)
print(r.url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all("div", class_="col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item")
print(len(items))
```**strong text**
````

Comment: It appears the page is dynamic, meaning that it only loads content when it is calles in a browser window. Did you try using Selenium? Find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58902915/9524424

Comment: BeautifulSoup/requests can't run JavaScript. SO if page uses JavaScript the you may have to use Selenium to control browser which can run JavaScript. OR you may try to find url used in `JavaScript/AJAX` to get data from server and then you can try to use it with `requests`.

Comment: Thanks guy, i will learn Selenium later, before i tried to use Selenium to control the mouse click only. That's first know, there is other way to get content for Javascript. Do you know any good website to learn crawl, because I realized If I want to understand how to crawl, I have to learn more like http, json, xml and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This page uses `JavaScript` to display items but `BeautifulSoup`/`requests` can't run `JavaScipt`.

Using `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `"Network"`) I found url used by `JavaScript` to get data from server as JSON so it doesn't even need `BeautifulSoup`.

To work correctly it needs all theses headers.

Without `User-Agent` and `X-Requested-With` it sends empty data.
Without `Referer` it doesn't send prices.

```
import requests

url = 'https://shopee.tw/api/v2/search_items/?by=pop&limit=30&match_id=1819984&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=shop&shop_categoryids=9271157&version=2'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer': 'https://shopee.tw/shop/1819984/search?shopCollection=9271157',
}    

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

data = r.json()

#print(data['items'][0].keys())

for item in data['items']:
    print('name:', item['name'])
    print('prince:', item['price'])
    print('sold:', item['historical_sold'])
    print('---')

#print(data['items'][0]) # for test only
```

Result:

```
name: 『現貨+預購』 Balea 精華膠囊 7 入
prince: 4900000
sold: 5104
---
name: 現貨供應 德國 Invisibobble 神奇魔髮圈流線魔髮圈
prince: 7500000
sold: 26
---
```

---

**BTW:** for test to see all values you can use `json` to format it with indentations

```
import json

print(json.dumps(data['items'][0], indent=4))
```

Result:

```
{
    "itemid": 1212735748,
    "welcome_package_info": null,
    "liked": false,
    "recommendation_info": null,
    "bundle_deal_info": null,
    "price_max_before_discount": -1,
    "image": "338673ff6f2b23d63514e5af85269d46",
    "is_cc_installment_payment_eligible": false,
    "shopid": 1819984,
    "can_use_wholesale": true,
    "group_buy_info": null,
    "reference_item_id": "",
    "currency": "TWD",
    "raw_discount": null,
    "show_free_shipping": false,
    "video_info_list": [],
    "ads_keyword": null,
    "collection_id": null,
    "images": [
        "338673ff6f2b23d63514e5af85269d46"
    ],
    "match_type": null,
    "price_before_discount": 0,
    "is_category_failed": false,
    "show_discount": 0,
    "cmt_count": 306,
    "view_count": 93,
    "display_name": null,
    "catid": 67,
    "json_data": null,
    "upcoming_flash_sale": null,
    "is_official_shop": false,
    "brand": "Dm Ebelin",
    "price_min": 4900000,
    "liked_count": 136,
    "can_use_bundle_deal": false,
    "show_official_shop_label": false,
    "coin_earn_label": null,
    "price_min_before_discount": -1,
    "cb_option": 0,
    "sold": 0,
    "deduction_info": null,
    "stock": 3647,
    "status": 1,
    "price_max": 4900000,
    "add_on_deal_info": null,
    "is_group_buy_item": null,
    "flash_sale": null,
    "price": 4900000,
    "shop_location": "\u53f0\u4e2d\u5e02\u6f6d\u5b50\u5340",
    "item_rating": {
        "rating_star": 4.996732,
        "rating_count": [
            306,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1,
            305
        ],
        "rcount_with_image": 11,
        "rcount_with_context": 139
    },
    "show_official_shop_label_in_title": false,
    "tier_variations": [],
    "is_adult": null,
    "discount": null,
    "flag": 65536,
    "is_non_cc_installment_payment_eligible": false,
    "has_lowest_price_guarantee": false,
    "has_group_buy_stock": false,
    "preview_info": null,
    "welcome_package_type": 0,
    "name": "\u300e\u73fe\u8ca8+\u9810\u8cfc\u300f Balea \u7cbe\u83ef\u81a0\u56ca 7 \u5165",
    "distance": null,
    "adsid": null,
    "ctime": 1527866201,
    "wholesale_tier_list": [
        {
            "min_count": 150,
            "price": 4700000,
            "max_count": 300
        },
        {
            "min_count": 301,
            "price": 4600000,
            "max_count": 1000
        },
        {
            "min_count": 1001,
            "price": 4500000,
            "max_count": null
        }
    ],
    "show_shopee_verified_label": false,
    "campaignid": null,
    "show_official_shop_label_in_normal_position": null,
    "item_status": "normal",
    "shopee_verified": false,
    "hidden_price_display": null,
    "size_chart": null,
    "item_type": 0,
    "shipping_icon_type": null,
    "campaign_stock": null,
    "label_ids": [],
    "service_by_shopee_flag": 0,
    "badge_icon_type": 0,
    "historical_sold": 5104,
    "transparent_background_image": ""
}
```

Comment: But I wanna get more what I want like the count of how many were sold.

Comment: If I wanna get how many were sold in this"https://shopee.tw/shop/1819984/search?shopCollection=9271157" page, I know that first item is sold up to 5,104. I cannot find it in JSON and the html data. Is it possible to use other way to make it happen?

Comment: when I display first `item` then I see `'historical_sold': 5104` - but only if I send `Referer`

Comment: I added example with `json.dumps(..., indent=4)` to show how to better see values in item.