# Crawl products' information from Shopee using JSON URL calls

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape products' information from Shopee website by using JSON URL calls. I am aware that my question is similar to the answer given in -  [How can I crawl the product items from shopee website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59557071/how-can-i-crawl-the-product-items-from-shopee-website/59557626#59557626).

However, my question involves a ***2-step process*** that requires me to get the product's url in order to proceed to the second step, and opens up possibilities for workarounds getting to it.

**The 2-step process is explained below:**

***Step 1*** involves inputting a keyword (for products that I want to search) into the search bar, then extract product information of all top products. Initially, I used Selenium and BeautifulSoup, but realised that getting JSON data from the server using URL call is the more efficient option.

```
import requests

Shopee_url = 'https://shopee.sg'
keyword_search = 'Lipton'
headers = {
 'User-Agent': 'Chrome',
 'Referer': '{}search?keyword={}'.format(Shopee_url, keyword_search)
}

url = 'https://shopee.sg/api/v2/search_items/?by=relevancy&keyword={}&limit=100&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search'.format(keyword_search)
#can change "relevancy" to "latest": to sort by latest products instead

# Shopee API request
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers).json()
```

Below is a sample of all the JSON data that returned from 1 product:

```
{
    "itemid": 7997227782,
    "price_max_before_discount": 990000,
    "item_status": "normal",
    "can_use_wholesale": false,
    "show_free_shipping": false,
    "display_name": null,
    "upcoming_flash_sale": null,
    "add_on_deal_info": null,
    "is_non_cc_installment_payment_eligible": false,
    "ctime": 1628604243,
    "name": "Lipton Infusions Fruit Tea, 20 Pyramid Teabags",
    "show_shopee_verified_label": true,
    "campaignid": 2768568,
    "size_chart": null,
    "service_by_shopee_flag": null,
    "historical_sold": 11,
    "campaign_stock": null,
    "reference_item_id": "",
    "recommendation_info": null,
    "bundle_deal_info": null,
    "has_lowest_price_guarantee": false,
    "shipping_icon_type": null,
    "overall_purchase_limit": null,
    "images": [
        "06770c2d7077dc5430a44f030f1efe48"
    ],
    "price_before_discount": 990000,
    "catid": 100629,
    "is_official_shop": false,
    "coin_earn_label": null,
    "sold": 11,
    "item_rating": {
        "rating_star": 5.0,
        "rating_count": [
            3,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            3
        ],
        "rcount_with_image": 1,
        "rcount_with_context": 1
    },
    "show_official_shop_label_in_title": false,
    "discount": "41%",
    "label_ids": [
        1000055,
        22,
        1007623
    ],
    "has_group_buy_stock": null,
    "algo_image": null,
    "tracking_info": {
        "multi_search_tracking": null,
        "viral_spu_tracking": null,
        "ruleid": null,
        "groupid": 0,
        "business_tracking": null
    },
    "pack_size": null,
    "badge_icon_type": 0,
    "liked": false,
    "is_on_flash_sale": false,
    "cmt_count": 3,
    "image": "06770c2d7077dc5430a44f030f1efe48",
    "recommendation_algorithm": null,
    "is_cc_installment_payment_eligible": false,
    "shopid": 323430152,
    "video_info_list": [],
    "ads_keyword": "lipton tea",
    "json_data": "aP///////////wFxO6BCgr9Dsj95+HOgMCiwqz+IAQI=",
    "view_count": 356,
    "voucher_info": null,
    "liked_count": 8,
    "show_official_shop_label": false,
    "price_min_before_discount": 990000,
    "show_discount": 41,
    "preview_info": null,
    "flag": 0,
    "exclusive_price_info": null,
    "distance": null,
    "wholesale_tier_list": [],
    "fe_flags": null,
    "group_buy_info": null,
    "shopee_verified": true,
    "hidden_price_display": null,
    "transparent_background_image": "",
    "welcome_package_info": null,
    "match_type": 1,
    "is_adult": false,
    "currency": "SGD",
    "raw_discount": 41,
    "is_preferred_plus_seller": false,
    "is_category_failed": false,
    "price_min": 585000,
    "can_use_bundle_deal": false,
    "cb_option": 0,
    "brand": null,
    "deduction_info": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFz5yPUIFAImyA4NRO+XPGonKqZTmkZlKacrYO7uw8Qx5HzU6gGT9zYYfnvHkpQbfctiPF/QqIikCqPGJnPHD8FOZqHDiw9HVccOiJwd5i0A5rN2o44A33/RihzLZeoP8w==",
    "stock": 125,
    "status": 1,
    "price_max": 585000,
    "is_group_buy_item": null,
    "flash_sale": null,
    "is_mart": null,
    "price": 585000,
    "shop_location": "Singapore",
    "tier_variations": [
        {
            "images": [
                "b392790c3b5749fbe9c08698d3ddb7ae",
                "c93868109beabc85fa4f47d21f7b0cf3",
                "b371c4379fd4f2a518cf4b5467bbe65b",
                "0dfc442c280866b596af8e25bb26f5f4",
                "e39ded7159a8d2595e3de664d289002e",
                "523d6df729a190003fabdc08f70e36ef",
                "409df69f3010e1cc11420ea5b88b1d48"
            ],
            "properties": [],
            "type": 0,
            "name": "Options",
            "options": [
                "Blue Fruit",
                "Calming Chamomile",
                "Citrus",
                "Forest Fruit",
                "Grape Raspberry",
                "Mandarin Orange",
                "Strawberry Mint"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "min_purchase_limit": null,
    "can_use_cod": false,
    "collection_id": null,
    "welcome_package_type": 0,
    "show_official_shop_label_in_normal_position": null,
    "adsid": 4974802,
    "item_type": 0,
    "spl_installment_tenure": null
}
```

Currently, I am able to extract the products' **name**, **price**, **sold quantity**, and **rating**; by appending the respective JSON data into various lists as shown below.

```
titles_list = []
prices_list = []
sold_list = []
ratings_list = []

for item in r['items']:
    titles_list.append(item['name'])
    prices_list.append(item['price_min'])
    sold_list.append(item['historical_sold'])
    ratings_list.append(item['item_rating']['rating_star'])
```

However, in order to proceed to step 2, I will need the products' URL as well, but I could not find it in the JSON data that returned. As...

***Step 2*** involves taking the products' URL so to access each product's webpage, in order to further scrape all the reviews for each product.

Similarly, the method used to scrape all the reviews in the product's webpage is done using JSON URL calls as shown below:

```
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

#url link is used manually here as for now
url = "https://shopee.sg/%E3%80%90Japan-limited%E3%80%91%E3%80%90Made-in-Japan%E3%80%91-Lipton-Flavor-Tea-Assortment-Pack-Tea-Bag-10-Bags-Japan-food-instant-Tea-%E3%80%90Direct-from-Japan%E3%80%91-i.219170680.4523492238?ads_keyword=wkdaelpmissisiht&adsid=238017&campaignid=160393&position=1"

r = re.search(r"i\.(\d+)\.(\d+)", url)
shop_id, item_id = r[1], r[2]
ratings_url = "https://shopee.sg/api/v2/item/get_ratings?filter=0&flag=1&itemid={item_id}&limit=20&offset={offset}&shopid={shop_id}&type=0"

offset = 0
d = {"username": [], "rating": [], "comment": []}
while True:
    data = requests.get(
        ratings_url.format(shop_id=shop_id, item_id=item_id, offset=offset)
    ).json()

    # uncomment this to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
    
    i = 1
    for i, rating in enumerate(data["data"]["ratings"], 1):
        d["username"].append(rating["author_username"])
        d["rating"].append(rating["rating_star"])
        d["comment"].append(rating["comment"])

        print(rating["author_username"])
        print(rating["rating_star"])
        print(rating["comment"])
        print("-" * 100)

    if i % 20:
        break

    offset += 20
   

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Sample Output:

```
l*****1
5
Reliable seller, repeat purchases, items are always well packaged & received in excellent condition.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
spyuc
5
Takes a while deliver as it’s shipped from Japan. Priced a bit on the high side. But taste good both hot and cold brewed.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
i*****r
5
Delivery took a week. Considered okay. Yet to try the teas but looks good.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As seen from the codes, I need the products' URL from ***Step 1*** in order to proceed to ***Step 2***, as ***Step 2*** requires the URL as an input.

Therefore, I am wondering how can I alter my codes in ***Step 1*** in order to retrieve the products' URLs, so that I can use each of the URLs to further scrape all the reviews for each product. Or is there any other workarounds that I can attempt in order to achieve my objective?

Apologies for the long post, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the 2 steps together, you only need "shopid" and "itemid" from the item:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


def get_ratings(shop_id, item_id):
    ratings_url = "https://shopee.sg/api/v2/item/get_ratings?filter=0&flag=1&itemid={item_id}&limit=20&offset={offset}&shopid={shop_id}&type=0"

    offset = 0
    d = {"username": [], "rating": [], "comment": []}
    while True:
        data = requests.get(
            ratings_url.format(shop_id=shop_id, item_id=item_id, offset=offset)
        ).json()

        # uncomment this to print all data:
        # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

        i = 1
        for i, rating in enumerate(data["data"]["ratings"], 1):
            d["username"].append(rating["author_username"])
            d["rating"].append(rating["rating_star"])
            d["comment"].append(rating["comment"])

        if i % 20:
            break

        offset += 20

    return d


Shopee_url = "https://shopee.sg"
keyword_search = "Lipton"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Chrome",
    "Referer": "{}search?keyword={}".format(Shopee_url, keyword_search),
}

url = "https://shopee.sg/api/v2/search_items/?by=relevancy&keyword={}&limit=100&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search".format(
    keyword_search
)
# can change "relevancy" to "latest": to sort by latest products instead

# Shopee API request
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

for item in r["items"]:
    print(item["name"])
    df = pd.DataFrame(get_ratings(item["shopid"], item["itemid"]))
    print(df.head()) # print only the head for brevity
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Lipton Infusions Fruit Tea, 20 Pyramid Teabags
        username  rating                                                                                               comment
0  blehhhbowling       5  Prompt delivery, been looking for these flavours everywhere in big name supermarkets but to no avail
1        d*****h       5                                                                                                      
2  sitisujanah13       5                                                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
【Japan limited】【Made in Japan】 Lipton Flavor Tea Assortment Pack Tea Bag 10 Bags Japan food  instant Tea 【Direct from Japan】
  username  rating                                                                                                                    comment
0  s*****e       5                                               约10天到货\n日本直运 买了5种不同的(花茶/调味茶来取代泡泡茶)\n还有特别款的全麦kitkat\n外包装是完整的\n日系商品的独特风味\n值得品尝
1  l*****1       5                       Reliable seller, repeat purchases, items are always well packaged & received in excellent condition.
2    spyuc       5  Takes a while deliver as it’s shipped from Japan. Priced a bit on the high side. But taste good both hot and cold brewed.
3  i*****r       5                                                 Delivery took a week. Considered okay. Yet to try the teas but looks good.
4  m*****y       4                                                      Delivery took abt 1 week. Have yet to try hope it's good. Long expiry
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Hi, the solution works perfectly! Can I ask how can I find out more about the different URL calls from Shopee? For example, the "ratings_url" that you provided above? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DonovanTan You can learn about different API calls if you open Firefox Developer Tools (Chrome has something similar) -> Network Tab. There you can see all calls the page is doing (you can filter the Json calls, observe the parameters etc.)

Comment: Oh I see, that is really helpful, appreciate it :)

Comment: Hi, I realised that the output actually has a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" if you scroll all the way to the end. The error is caused by the code "for i, rating in enumerate(data["data"]["ratings"], 1):".