# How can I get dictionaries in a tag of ResultSet using bs4?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jsrender

I'm trying to scrape some data from websites, just started yesterday, but I can't get the data I want from the content I scrape from that website.

```
try:    
html=urlopen('https://shopee.tw/api/v4/search/search_items?by=relevancy&keyword=%E9%81%8B%E5%8B%95%E9%9E%8B&limit=60&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&scenario=PAGE_GLOBAL_SEARCH&version=2')
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
except URLError as e:
    print('THe server is not found')
else:
    print('worked') 
bs=BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
bodydata=bs.find_all('body')
```

How can I get the specific dictionary inside bodydata?
I tried

```
for x in bodydata:
    print(x.get_text())
```

but the result is a string variable. How can I get certain dictionary, if the bodydata look like this?

```
{"bff_meta":null,"error":null,"error_msg":null,"reserved_keyword":null,"suggestion_algorithm":null,"algorithm":"eyJzZWFyY2giOiIwLmEuNjE2N0BPUEtVVVVFSklXSVBSWEtSVVNaQUVST1ZRUFZaWE5URk1FT05SWTBEWVRZSkcxRVRHVkVTMlpKM1BRNzBaQzExNUdPMTgyIn0=","total_count":3177,"nomore":false,"items":[{"item_basic":{"itemid":10288392472,"shopid":451862210,....
```

Comment: We need more to go on? This is kinda vague.

Comment: @AaronCloud  the stuff I get from the website right now contains some dictionaries which are the stuff I want, but I don't know how to extract them from the whole chunk of information, I use find_all to get the part which tag is body, but I don't know how to dig further.

Comment: Okay, what are you looking to pull out. And how did you want it to look?
Does this answer your question??

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59557071/how-can-i-crawl-the-product-items-from-shopee-website

Comment: @AaronCloud I now get it, I didn't know I should transform it with json().

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example above:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://shopee.tw/api/v4/search/search_items?by=relevancy&keyword=%E9%81%8B%E5%8B%95%E9%9E%8B&limit=60&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&scenario=PAGE_GLOBAL_SEARCH&version=2')
# print(r.json()) ## you can print it, look at it, extract other key/values from it, etc. For example, to extract 'items' and put them into a dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['items'])
df
```

This returns a dataframe like the one below, 60 rows × 22 columns:

```
item_basic  adsid   campaignid  distance    match_type  ads_keyword deduction_info  collection_id   display_name    campaign_stock  ... itemid  shopid  algo_image  fe_flags    item_type   foody_item  search_item_tracking    bff_item_tracking   personalized_labels biz_json
0   {'itemid': 10288392472, 'shopid': 451862210, '...   42222082.0  26817031.0  None    1.0 350 鞋子正品    U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MI2w8H7BMT9hDxZHHknw7FqdFT...   None    None    None    ... 10288392472 451862210   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1010729,1014629],"is_on_flash_sa...   None    None
1   {'itemid': 15649674773, 'shopid': 479604969, '...   40526742.0  25502467.0  None    1.0 休閒白鞋    U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MC0e79wRsWCGLqC4Kuico0aGGn...   None    None    None    ... 15649674773 479604969   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":null,"is_on_flash_sale":false,"is...   None    None
2   {'itemid': 5759477451, 'shopid': 275457974, 'n...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 5759477451  275457974   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1008416,1008415,1010729,1010733,...   None    None
3   {'itemid': 15258032169, 'shopid': 570620255, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 15258032169 570620255   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1014629,1002127,1007681,1007880,...   None    None
4   {'itemid': 10475499089, 'shopid': 117981382, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 10475499089 117981382   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1010729,1011331,1011333,1011847,...   None    None
5   {'itemid': 13088655898, 'shopid': 342768515, '...   52175386.0  34432248.0  None    0.0 wkdaelpmissisiht    U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MCVLBvV/hLJndlLT3P7ryGL8AC...   None    None    None    ... 13088655898 342768515   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1010445,1010729,1010736,1011292,...   None    None
6   {'itemid': 7765671062, 'shopid': 275457974, 'n...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 7765671062  275457974   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[1000,0,1000],"group...   {"label_ids":[1008416,1008415,1010729,1010733,...   None    None
7   {'itemid': 10405964649, 'shopid': 892903, 'nam...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 10405964649 892903  None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[16,1000140,1000138,1001499,10045...   None    None
8   {'itemid': 14151724538, 'shopid': 612578498, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 14151724538 612578498   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1012634,1013629,1013627,1013618,...   None    None
9   {'itemid': 16510149105, 'shopid': 107174380, '...   43690945.0  27940756.0  None    0.0 wkdaelpmissisiht    U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MEo9yrrmUKCIs04A/Sl+dth6dx...   None    None    None    ... 16510149105 107174380   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1014629,1014914,1014915,1015983,...   None    None
10  {'itemid': 17537486071, 'shopid': 570620255, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 17537486071 570620255   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1012634,1014629,1002127,1007681,...   None    None
11  {'itemid': 10966656779, 'shopid': 223349546, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 10966656779 223349546   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[1000,1000],"groupid...   {"label_ids":[1014629,1013623,1014915],"is_on_...   None    None
12  {'itemid': 13461133395, 'shopid': 612578498, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 13461133395 612578498   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0,1000,1000],"group...   {"label_ids":[1013629,1013627,1013618,1014629,...   None    None
13  {'itemid': 21624649473, 'shopid': 819002215, '...   52491528.0  34675541.0  None    1.0 nike    U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MABOFQgxtYRn6dl2TJ+zhF70dU...   None    None    None    ... 21624649473 819002215   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":null,"is_on_flash_sale":false,"is...   None    None
14  {'itemid': 17858909983, 'shopid': 565183238, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 17858909983 565183238   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1014629,1012634,1014912,1007880,...   None    None
15  {'itemid': 10387321865, 'shopid': 117981382, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 10387321865 117981382   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1010729,1011331,1011333,1011847,...   None    None
16  {'itemid': 15982004503, 'shopid': 276970990, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 15982004503 276970990   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1010729,1010733,1011331,1011333,...   None    None
17  {'itemid': 16128180376, 'shopid': 440266562, '...   43415099.0  27730568.0  None    0.0 wkdaelpmissisiht    U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MD90vWe3xxVRRspKmttqOU9oB+...   None    None    None    ... 16128180376 440266562   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1014629,1014589,1014914,1015986,...   None    None
18  {'itemid': 11801176535, 'shopid': 36011643, 'n...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 11801176535 36011643    None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1010729,1011292,1011926,1012346,...   None    None
19  {'itemid': 15008651489, 'shopid': 223349546, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 15008651489 223349546   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1014629,1014915],"is_on_flash_sa...   None    None
20  {'itemid': 17015191947, 'shopid': 264561849, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 17015191947 264561849   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1012634,1012808,1013627,1014629,...   None    None
21  {'itemid': 20424652485, 'shopid': 819002215, '...   52490421.0  34675539.0  None    1.0 慢跑鞋 U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1ML5FgkDFq3u0YwbmFFITddg3kW...   None    None    None    ... 20424652485 819002215   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":null,"is_on_flash_sale":false,"is...   None    None
22  {'itemid': 15663824790, 'shopid': 424421393, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 15663824790 424421393   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1006579,1006629,1007465,1010729,...   None    None
23  {'itemid': 9822950083, 'shopid': 2304498, 'nam...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 9822950083  2304498 None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[1000,1000],"groupid...   {"label_ids":[1000140,1001499,1002127,1005833,...   None    None
24  {'itemid': 12605212937, 'shopid': 2443283, 'na...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 12605212937 2443283 None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[16,1000140,1001499,1002936,10015...   None    None
25  {'itemid': 17957096336, 'shopid': 752665010, '...   46234219.0  29894142.0  None    0.0 wkdaelpmissisiht    U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MI9QfVgkJYuv+S3LdJULXcsn0T...   None    None    None    ... 17957096336 752665010   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":null,"is_on_flash_sale":false,"is...   None    None
26  {'itemid': 21104501514, 'shopid': 555360855, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 21104501514 555360855   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[1000,1000],"groupid...   {"label_ids":[1010733,1011292,1011331,1011333,...   None    None
27  {'itemid': 11582152525, 'shopid': 607317086, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 11582152525 607317086   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1012634,1012806,1013629,1013627,...   None    None
28  {'itemid': 10955439292, 'shopid': 12616228, 'n...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 10955439292 12616228    None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1010729,1010733,1011331,1011333,...   None    None
29  {'itemid': 14888873227, 'shopid': 230771967, '...   51925081.0  34232774.0  None    1.0 327 U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MLztFn/QffvV2OrivgXmINmtXs...   None    None    None    ... 14888873227 230771967   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1014629],"is_on_flash_sale":fals...   None    None
30  {'itemid': 5571523506, 'shopid': 275457974, 'n...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 5571523506  275457974   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1008416,1008415,1010729,1010733,...   None    None
31  {'itemid': 16400569451, 'shopid': 612578498, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 16400569451 612578498   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1012634,1013629,1013627,1013618,...   None    None
32  {'itemid': 5180067072, 'shopid': 326356101, 'n...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 5180067072  326356101   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[1000,0,1000],"group...   {"label_ids":[1009753,1010729,1010733,1010735,...   None    None
33  {'itemid': 21104501514, 'shopid': 555360855, '...   48758219.0  31615286.0  None    1.0 跑鞋  U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MH4HwIKJa+WQUrtlpBG2L8VzNJ...   None    None    None    ... 21104501514 555360855   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1010733,1011292,1011331,1011333,...   None    None
34  {'itemid': 14651880343, 'shopid': 612578498, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 14651880343 612578498   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1012634,1013629,1013627,1013618,...   None    None
35  {'itemid': 10278011366, 'shopid': 365689255, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 10278011366 365689255   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1004778,1004779,1004780,1005131,...   None    None
36  {'itemid': 4065692740, 'shopid': 275457974, 'n...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 4065692740  275457974   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[1000,0,1000],"group...   {"label_ids":[1008416,1008415,1010729,1010733,...   None    None
37  {'itemid': 13741712216, 'shopid': 479604969, '...   41765043.0  22743315.0  None    1.0 鞋   U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MMiNM31En9NgXKp7ZdEFgn2dmq...   None    None    None    ... 13741712216 479604969   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":null,"is_on_flash_sale":false,"is...   None    None
38  {'itemid': 14129123236, 'shopid': 450599940, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 14129123236 450599940   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[1000,0,1000],"group...   {"label_ids":[1006112,1006579,1006629,1008403,...   None    None
39  {'itemid': 11390620224, 'shopid': 4636818, 'na...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 11390620224 4636818 None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[1000,1000],"groupid...   {"label_ids":[1014629,1015983,1015984,1015987,...   None    None
40  {'itemid': 11865538830, 'shopid': 223349546, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 11865538830 223349546   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1014629,1014915],"is_on_flash_sa...   None    None
41  {'itemid': 15663824790, 'shopid': 424421393, '...   43074045.0  27477258.0  None    1.0 運動鞋 U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MFTA1+Y8XGP+sTjh6Gm374Vsnk...   None    None    None    ... 15663824790 424421393   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1006579,1006629,1007465,1010729,...   None    None
42  {'itemid': 16447619272, 'shopid': 17527952, 'n...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 16447619272 17527952    None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[16,1000140,1000138,1001499,10000...   None    None
43  {'itemid': 16245159961, 'shopid': 2157594, 'na...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 16245159961 2157594 None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1002127,1009753,1005701,1010729,...   None    None
44  {'itemid': 16715057285, 'shopid': 264561849, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 16715057285 264561849   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1012634,1012808,1013627,1014629,...   None    None
45  {'itemid': 16237447945, 'shopid': 390967233, '...   44116223.0  28258393.0  None    0.0 wkdaelpmissisiht    U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MMcvMXXAR04k6McXiNefl/J7EP...   None    None    None    ... 16237447945 390967233   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1009753,1010729,1010733,1011331,...   None    None
46  {'itemid': 11286328992, 'shopid': 570620255, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 11286328992 570620255   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1012634,1014629,1002127,1007681,...   None    None
47  {'itemid': 12974747270, 'shopid': 253926413, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 12974747270 253926413   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1004846,1004778,1004779,1004780,...   None    None
48  {'itemid': 7591220980, 'shopid': 290994282, 'n...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 7591220980  290994282   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1000449,1000138,1001499,1001511,...   None    None
49  {'itemid': 3096197829, 'shopid': 39623462, 'na...   35351777.0  21618459.0  None    1.0 工作鞋 U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MD90vWe3xxVRRspKmttqOU9bfO...   None    None    None    ... 3096197829  39623462    None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1010729,1010734,1011331,1011333,...   None    None
50  {'itemid': 12139827160, 'shopid': 538703151, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 12139827160 538703151   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1010733,1008416,1011292,1011331,...   None    None
51  {'itemid': 1934878030, 'shopid': 2157594, 'nam...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 1934878030  2157594 None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1002127,1009753,1005701,1010729,...   None    None
52  {'itemid': 16846682501, 'shopid': 342768515, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 16846682501 342768515   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[1000,1000],"groupid...   {"label_ids":[1010445,1010729,1010736,1011292,...   None    None
53  {'itemid': 16846682501, 'shopid': 342768515, '...   45338925.0  29188974.0  None    1.0 運動鞋 U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MD90vWe3xxVRRspKmttqOU/sPA...   None    None    None    ... 16846682501 342768515   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1010445,1010729,1010736,1011292,...   None    None
54  {'itemid': 12180979071, 'shopid': 594162705, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 12180979071 594162705   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1011292,1011847,1011924,1011926,...   None    None
55  {'itemid': 16557416632, 'shopid': 752665010, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 16557416632 752665010   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1015986,1015987],"is_on_flash_sa...   None    None
56  {'itemid': 16928780052, 'shopid': 298455536, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 16928780052 298455536   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1010729,1010733,1011331,1011333,...   None    None
57  {'itemid': 6559220933, 'shopid': 277776420, 'n...   33063174.0  19876164.0  None    0.0 運動鞋 U1lQYVlnQUFBQUJCUkc1MAbKJeEtNVZYYisoRB+n4q+ena...   None    None    None    ... 6559220933  277776420   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":true,"groupid":0,"fe_flags":"{}","it...   {"label_ids":[1004779,1009692,1009505,1010713,...   None    None
58  {'itemid': 68282596, 'shopid': 4802609, 'name'...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 68282596    4802609 None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[16,1000508,1000138,1001499,10028...   None    None
59  {'itemid': 16512648958, 'shopid': 264561849, '...   NaN NaN None    NaN None    None    None    None    None    ... 16512648958 264561849   None    None    1   None    {"is_ads":false,"ruleids":[0],"groupid":0,"fe_...   {"label_ids":[1012634,1012808,1013627,1014629,...   None    None
```